# How instantaneous speed is defined as magnitude of instant velocity?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, differentiation, speed

Let $s=$distance (a variable)
we define instantaneous speed = magnitude $\left[\frac{ds}{dt}\right]$.
However instantaneous speed is also defined as magnitude of instantaneous velocity
i.e. instantaneous speed=mod $v$ [$v$=velocity].
How can we prove mathematically that magnitude $\left[\frac{ds}{dt}\right]$= magnitude $v$.

Comment: I have rewritten the terms as used in standards/Please help

Comment: "instantaneous speed=mod(dv/dt)[v=velocity] ": that's wrong - where did you see that? And what is "mod"?

Comment: @Nick It looks like "mod" is supposed to mean magnitude perhaps?

Comment: mod= modulus=magnitude of velocity

Comment: Yes, it seems so, but it's non-standard (and the equation is still wrong).

Comment: Instantaneous speed is not ds/dt is your issue. Speed is always positive. ds/dt can be negative. Therefore, the correct relation for instantaneous speed is the magnitude of ds/dt.

Comment: The thing is you are not saying "modulus of velocity", you are saying "modulus of dv/dt" i.e. modulus of acceleration.

Comment: @Nick.Sorry!!!  i have modified my confusion.Please guide

Comment: @ Aaron Stevens , Its modulus of ds/dt.I have remodified my question

Comment: saying that $|\vec{v}|=\left| \frac{ds}{dt} \right|$ is false. It is $v=\left| \frac{d\vec{s}}{dt} \right|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to prove is just a definition.

$\frac{ds}{dt}$ is the velocity $v$.

$\frac{ds}{dt} = v$.

Therefore the magnitude of $\frac{ds}{dt}$ is the same thing as the magnitude of the velocity $v$

Answer (score 0):

I tried and worked as under
for small displacement dr ( dr is a vector,where ever written in this answer)
|dr|=|ds| , where ds is small  distance
so
v=dr/dt,  v is velocity vector
and |v|=|dr|/dt 
       =|ds|/dt = |ds/dt|
       =instantaneous speed
so instantaneous speed is defined as |ds|/dt as well as |v| i.e. the 
magnitude of instantaneous velocity